What do the red dots next to Trials in the Pitch Black Stone mean?
When viewing a Trial in the Pitch Black Stone, there are anywhere from 1 to 5 red dots on the right side of the screen next to each Trial. What do the red dots next to a Trial mean?


Note that there's an Info button for stuff like this, as the bottom-right says, hit Y!
And from that Info screen:

Beware the Eyes! The more Eyes you see, the tougher the Chaos Trial. New Trials will be revealed as you progress. Go with Chaos!


It's the difficulty indicator.

The difficulty of any Chaos Trial is indicated by the number of red eyes beside it, ranging from one to five eyes.

Source, TheGamer.

One presumably being the easiest?

@Valorum that's correct
